# Outputting \n as a line break when returning string as a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

This is hopefully very simple one and I think it lies in the encoding.

I have a `string` which contains `\n` for new lines

```
public ActionResult DownloadText(int id)
{
    var text = "BB2B-XX2A-F2CR-2MMQ-K79A\n3AP2-PH3H-M2QE-2DRH-D73A\nGPD3-AU3Q-P2DN-2FEX-P86A";
    return File(new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(tempKeys.ToString()), "text/plain", "Key"+ id.ToString() + ".txt");

}
```

I would like to display each item on a different line when output in the text file.

> BB2B-XX2A-F2CR-2MMQ-K79A
>
> 3AP2-PH3H-M2QE-2DRH-D73A
>
> GPD3-AU3Q-P2DN-2FEX-P86A

Comment: text variable is declared but isn't being used in your example. Could you update your example to give a little more information on what you're trying to accomplish. Is "tempKeys.ToString()" supposed to be "text" instead?

Comment: So what is the output of your existing code?

Comment: Have you saved the resulting file and checked if it indeed contains new lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So change the `\n` to the newline sequence you want. Probably the easiest way, assuming that your text is a string, is:

```
text = text.Replace("\n", Environment.Newline);
```

Comment: Thanks alot I thought it would be simple